# 日本語に違和感：htmlのdescription metaタグ

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

なんとなく（？）ソースコードを見ていて気がつきました。

```
<meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心の人向けの質問と回答のサイトです。" />
```

原文は

> Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers

ですので、

「熱狂的でプロフェッショナルなプログラマーのためのQ&A」

が直訳かなとおもいます（自信はない）。
少なくとも「熱心の人」は「熱心な人」です。

Comment: ツアーページの冒頭にも出てくるので、露出度が高め (優先度高め) の文言だと思います。あとプロフィールバナーのaltにも。

Answer (score 3):

This could be rather important, because Twitter uses this data in order to determine how to expand links to us as people post them on Twitter. As it's a *meta* tag, I don't believe it's currently localized the way the rest of the strings are, so we're going to make sure it's something we can work on in Transifex and go from there.

We also need to look at any other 'special' meta markup and make sure individual sites can control this as needed.

Answer (score 0):

`熱狂的でプロフェッショナルなプログラマーのためのQ&A`に更新しました。

Comment: 問題になっているのは「プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心の人向けの質問と回答のサイトです。」という文言です。回答の最初のコードブロックで、右の方にスクロールすると`content=`属性に含まれていると思います。メインサイトのトップやツアー、ヘルプセンタートップで確認しました。