# 日本語に違和感：プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心の人向けの質問と回答のサイト

Tags: バグ, 翻訳

ログインしていない状態でトップにアクセスしたときの次の文言が気になります。

> スタック・オーバーフロー は、プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心の人 の質問と回答のサイトです。100% 無料で、登録不要です。

原文はこれです。

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's 100% free, no registration required.

この表記は `og:description` にも含まれていて、こちらは過去に[メタで質問、修正されました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363/8000)。

ツアーページ冒頭に使われているものを参考に訳すとこんな感じでしょうか。

> スタック・オーバーフロー は、職業プログラマーから週末プログラマーまで、プログラミングに情熱をそそぐ人のためのQ&Aサイトです。登録なしでご利用いただけます。

---

When you are not logged in and access the top page you get the following phrase:

> スタック・オーバーフロー は、プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心の人 の質問と回答のサイトです。100% 無料で、登録不要です。

This is the English:

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's 100% free, no registration required.

This same phrase is also contained in `og:description` which was [changed in the past on meta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363/8000)

These should be changed to match what is on the tour page:

> スタック・オーバーフロー は、職業プログラマーから週末プログラマーまで、プログラミングに情熱をそそぐ人のためのQ&Aサイトです。登録なしでご利用いただけます。

Comment: これ英文を読むと明らかに誤訳で、professional and enthusiast　はセットで　programmers　を修飾している。
つまりプロフェッショナルかつ熱狂的なプログラマーのための～

Comment: @プリン  どうやら少なくとも[「明らかに誤訳」というほどではない](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/54433/) みたいです．