# 英語が残っている:ログインせずにトップページを見たときに出るサイトの説明

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

場所:[トップページ](http://ja.stackoverflow.com)(ログインしていない状態)

[image]

---

厳密に言えば、原文が変更されたためこの文章も英語になった、が正しいと思います。

原文:

> スタック・オーバーフロー is a question and answer site for プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心の人. Join them; it only takes a minute:

参考
[日本語に違和感：プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心の人向けの質問と回答のサイト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1733/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AB%E9%81%95%E5%92%8C%E6%84%9F-%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%81%A8%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%81%AB%E7%86%B1%E5%BF%83%E3%81%AE%E4%BA%BA%E5%90%91%E3%81%91%E3%81%AE%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%A8%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Transifex上で翻訳しました](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/66242206?q=join%20them)。

次回のビルドに適用します。